# Почему клиент не может соединиться с удаленным сервером?

Tags: сокеты, java, сокет

Сделал Клиент (Client.class) и Сервер (Server.class). При запуске клиента вводится Ip и порт и он поключается к Серверу. Когда всё делается на одном компе, всё работает, я ввожу Ip: 127.0.0.1 и порт: 6666 и клиент начинает посылать сообщения Серверу, а Сервер их принимает и выводит. Всё ок. Но я решил скинуть Server.clas другу. Он его запустил и сказал мне свой ип. Я ввёл его ип в Клиенте и порт: 6666. Но не мог к нему подключиться. И он ко мне тоже. Ничего, что у меня Linux, а у него Windows?

В чём может быть проблема?

Server.java:

```
import java.net.*;
import java.io.*;

public class Server {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int port = 6666;
        try {
            ServerSocket ss = new ServerSocket(port);
            System.out.println("Waiting for client...");

            Socket socket = ss.accept();
            print("Client opened...\n");

            InputStream sin = socket.getInputStream();
            OutputStream sout = socket.getOutputStream();

            DataInputStream in = new DataInputStream(sin);
            DataOutputStream out = new DataOutputStream(sout);

            String line = null;
            while (true) {
                line = in .readUTF();
                System.out.println("Waiting for the next line...");
                System.out.println("Client: " + line);
                print("\n");
            }
        } catch (Exception x) {
            print("Error: Client is closed!\n");
        }
    }
    static void print(String s) {
        System.out.print(s);
    }
}
```

Client.java:

```
import java.net.*;
import java.io.*;

public class Client {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int serverPort = 0;
        String address = null;

        try {
            BufferedReader keyboard = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System. in ));
            print("Type address of the server: ");
            address = keyboard.readLine();
            print("Type port of the server: ");
            serverPort = Integer.parseInt(keyboard.readLine());

            InetAddress ipAddress = InetAddress.getByName(address);
            Socket socket = new Socket(ipAddress, serverPort);

            InputStream sin = socket.getInputStream();
            OutputStream sout = socket.getOutputStream();

            DataInputStream in = new DataInputStream(sin);
            DataOutputStream out = new DataOutputStream(sout);

            String line = null;
            print("Type the line: ");
            while (true) {
                line = keyboard.readLine();
                System.out.println("Sending this line to the server...");
                out.writeUTF(line);
                out.flush();
                System.out.println();
                print("Type the next line: ");
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println("Error: Server don't found!");
        }
    }
    static void print(String s) {
        System.out.print(s);
    }
}
```

Comment: права на внешнее подключение для порта пропиши, может быть в этом все дело - режет фаерволл

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Windows и Linux - это не важно.

Проблема в том, что вы оба, наверняка, под NAT-ом. Обменялись вы локальными IP, а они за ближайшим роутером ничего не значат.

Нужен или статический IP, или "хитрые" сетевые штучки, обычно связанные с настройкой роутера.

Comment: Спасибо. Может быть надо вводить не ИП адрес, а имя компьютера? Например, уменя сейчас ip-83-149-3-98.nwgsm.ru. http://2ip.ru/

Comment: google: what is my ip

Comment: Если Ваш компьютер пингуется по имени от друга, то можете запустить на нем *сервер*. В этом случае обмен должен идти, даже если клиент под NAT.

Быстренько посмотрел, nslookup дает адрес, но ping не идет (traceroute тоже). Конечно, это может означать только то, что ICMP на Вашем роутере закрыт.

Если у Вас есть TCP открытые (и LISTEN) порты, потестируйте соединение telnet-ом.

Comment: А лучше не телнет, а netcat (http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Netcat). Может работать и клиентом, и сервером. Есть порт и под Windows